# How to make one single setup file of whole project?

Tags: c#, project, installation

I have complete my C# project and its working great,
Now i want to make a Setup / Installation file of my Completed C# project, so i can install it on any Machine and use it, just like a Software we download and install them on our PC and use them.

So please tell me that, how can i make single Setup file of my Completed C# Project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options, some are:

[Visual Studio Setup Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Package-for-Csharp-Windows-Applica)

[ClickOnce Deployment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17003/ClickOnce-Quick-steps-to-Deploy-Install-and-Update)

[Wix(Advanced)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have these  options:

- Use Visual Studios Setup Project, adding a new setup deployment project to your existing solution, as described  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Package-for-Csharp-Windows-Applica)
- Use  [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)